# CSS acting different on localhost

Tags: css, localhost, font-face

I'm working on a website, and I wanted to show it to someone. So I set up a webserver. Now I'm getting some strange behavior when I'm trying to reach the website via LAN instead of using my localhost.

First of all, when I visit the page in my localhost, everything seems to be rendered much smaller. I designed the page at a width etc. because it looks good. Now when I visit the site it fills up the whole page.

Secondly, I'm using `@font-face` for the titles etc. This works on my localhost, but not when I visit the page via my network.

And last, when I visit the page on my phone (using 3g, so not my home network), the css is not rendered at all.

Can you explain this strange behavior?

Comment: The behavior might be coming from the code itself. Can you provide links/code to the CSS in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has got to be that some of the stylesheets are not getting delivered when you view over the LAN.

When you look in Firebug NET tab (or similar) can you verify that all the stylesheets are being included and loaded (no 404s).

Also, if you look at the element that should have a font-face (for example) set, and check its styles, what is being applied?  Is it that the styles are not there, or are they there and not being applied as you expect?  (I am thinking the former).

---

> Everything is working now, except for one thing. My phone only shows
>   the right font for only the capitols. Any ideas on this?

If you look at the text with incorrect font in DOM inspector, does it show that the style is being applied?

Comment: Thank you, this helps al lot. I saw that my stylesheets where taken from the localhost, so when viewing from this computer and it looked for the stylesheet it was found. From my phone it didn't find the stylesheet. It has no localhost. Appearently font-face doesn't work in localhost either way.

Comment: Everything is working now, except for one thing. My phone only shows the right font for only the capitols. Any ideas on this?

Comment: Glad that helped.  Added a comment to answer re: text styling